# Can't find a way to return matrix in MEX without causing memory leak in GPU

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, cuda, gpgpu, mex

I have the following code, which casues memory leaks:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])
{

    const mxGPUArray * inp=mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]);
    const mxGPUArray * ms=mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[1]);
    const double * inpPtr=(const double*) mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(inp);
    const double * msPtr=(const double*) mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(ms);
    mxGPUArray * out=mxGPUCopyFromMxArray(prhs[2]);
    double * outPtr=(double* ) mxGPUGetData(out);
    func<<<blocksN,threadsN,ShreadMemSize,stream1>>>(outPtr, inpPtr, msPtr, inpSize[0],0);
    plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(out);
mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(inp);
mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(ms);
mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(out);
}
```

This code works, but causes memory leaks on GPU, presumably because `plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(out);` causes more memory to be allocated without releasing previously allocated memory. I pass to this code, as the 3rd input, a GPUArray matrix of 0-s of the size the output should be. the rest of the inputs are matrices to be processed.

All my attempts to fix this have failed. I tried:

1. removing the `const`, and getting `rhs[2]`'s pointer to the data (`mxGetData`/`mxGetPr`), passing it as `outPtr` (gives an unknown error when using talonmies's gpuErrchk)
2. [Creating a new numeric array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericarray.html) and [setting the pointer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetpr.html) to be prhs[2]'s pointer - didn't work either.

and some other little things, all of which failed miserably.

Any ideas as to why there don't work, and what will work? basically I need a way not to allocate any more memory. I can't figure out how to modify `prhs[2]` or get `plhs[0]` to use `prhs[2]`'s pointer...
I am using MATLAB 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround has been offered [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86194#answer_95833)

This solves my problem. hope it will be of help to others as well, until they fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for MEX cuda programming is tough. After much searching, I found a function that solved a major problem: `mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU` helped me deal with the problem of passing a pointer obtained from a mxArray to a kernel (which causes a problem, since the pointer needs to be obtained from a mxGPUArray, or from an object created by the function I mentioned.
for an example, copy-paste this into MATLAB:

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/mx/mxcalcsinglesubscript.c']);
```